# Is it save to Upgrade a lamp-stack without losing configurations?

Tags: linux, centos7, lamp, upgrade

I am rather new to the whole Server Administration thing.

**I am currently running a CentOS 7 Server with the following lamp-stack versions:**

- Apache(httpd) - 2.4.6 (CentOS)
- php - 7.1.12 (IUS)
- MariaDB - 5.5.56 (CentOS)
- phpMyAdmin - 4.7.5 (Manual via zip)

**I would like to upgrade to the following versions:**

- Apache(httpd) - 2.4.29 (CodeIt, latest at the time of writing)
- php - 7.2.x (probably remi)
- MariaDB - 10.2.12 (mariadb.org, latest stable release as of time of writing)
- phpMyAdmin - 4.7.7 (Manual via zip)

**Now my Question:**

Can I do those upgrades without losing configurations or do I need to do backups of specific files so I do not lose them?
If I do need to do backups it would be nice when someone can pinpoint me to them.

**Additional Information to the Server:**

- The Server is running 5 Websites, all of them including SSL
- The Server is running a Mailserver using Postfix, Dovecot, OpenDKIM and a database for user accounts
- The Server is running a web based Cloud (Owncloud)
- The Server is running 3 Gameservers (Minecraft)
- I am the only one with SSH access
- I would not necessarily consider it a production Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after testing for quite some time it turns out most things can be safely upgraded, however mariadb was not cooperating easily.

If anyone happens to want to do the same thing, those things worked for me:

**The following services were able to Upgrade without issues while retaining the config file:**

- ***Apache(httpd)*** - as reference material I used this [Tutorial](https://crosp.net/blog/administration/install-latest-apache-server-centos-7/).

  - In short: 
    `` cd /etc/yum.repos.d && wget https://repo.codeit.guru/codeit.el`rpm -q --qf "%{VERSION}" $(rpm -q --whatprovides redhat-release)`.repo ``
  - after that just `yum update` worked and replaced the packages with the new ones
- ***phpMyAdmin*** - as reference I just copied the layout of a preinstalled phpMyAdmin

  - download latest Version from official [Website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/) 
    `wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.7.7/phpMyAdmin-4.7.7-all-languages.zip`
  - unzip the file and then move it to `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/`
  - change `CONFIG_DIR` Variable of `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/vendor_config.php` to `/etc/phpMyAdmin/` so it can read the config.inc.php
- ***php*** - as reference I followed Remi's [Configuration Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions

  - after @Remi Collet had corrected me in installing a single php version, the installation itself worked flawlessly (see his answer for installation instructions)
  - due to the fact that [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/) does not support php7.2, I had to install a multiversion of php7.1 simultaneously, thanks to php-fpm that wasn't difficult to get it to work on the webserver.

**The following services had complications during the upgrade**

- ***MariaDB*** - as reference I followed this [Tutorial](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/installing-mariadb-10-centos-7-rhel-7)

  - first I tried using `yum update`
    it found the packages to replace but ended up crashing everything related to mysql. So I did a full reinstall
  - Postfix depends on MariaDB, therefore a backup of `/etc/postfix` is recommended
  - due to my attempts of just using update I had to `kill [ProcessId]` of all the processes run by the mysql daemon, otherwise it will fail to start with a message similar to: 
    `[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11`
    `[NOTE] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.`
  - all databases remained

**Summary:**

The lamp stack is able to be upgraded while retaining most configuration files. Only while installing mariadb you may need to do backups of configs of dependent services e.g. postfix (although it get's also done automatically by the system)

Comment: Notice: phpMyAdmin is also available in "remi" repository (as the repo replace lot of packages, you may need to select the ones you want from it), it also includes some PHP 7.2 patch (at least in php-tcpdf)

Answer (score 1):

> php - 7.2.x (As soon as IUS has it ready as an RPM since I dislike how remi places the files in /etc/opt/remi/)

Files are in /opt only if you choose "multiple versions" (SCL)

If you choose "single version", files will be in standard paths

Followiong the [Wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

In short:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
yum update
```

Comment: Notice: server is currently under maintained, should be back online shortly (btw, mirrors are available)

Comment: oh okay, guess I am gonna try that out once the instructions are back online. Does it ship a php Module for httpd because I think when I tested your distribution, I couldn't find a mod_php with yum unless it gets automatically added when using the single version.

Comment: Yes, the "php" package provides mod_php, btw, FPM is IMHO far better

Comment: all righty now that I was able to test it since your server is back online, it seemed to have worked flawlessly in the test environement replacing php71u with your php72, only issue it had was php-mcrypt but I assume it is no longer supported/deprecated?

Comment: mcrypt is indeed deprecated, and dropped from php. BTW php-pecl-mcrypt is available for legacy app, if you really want this dead cow, read https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2015/07/07/About-libmcrypt-and-php-mcrypt